# Limit number of foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

Let's take this example:

```
class Team (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=30)

class Round (models.Model):
    round_number = models.IntegerField('Round', editable=False) #Auto-incrementing per Team
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

There is a limit of 3 rounds. How can I raise an error inside the Admin and generally prevent a team from having more than 3 Rounds?

Comment: Just an idea: use choices to limit the IntegerField: `round_number=models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)` CHOICES is a list with tuples.

Comment: @alejoss jes, but this will not work as the round_number field is auto-incrementing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you need to override the form:

```
class RoundAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_team(self):
        team = self.cleaned_data['team']
        if team.round_set.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).count() == 3:
            raise ValidationError('Max three rounds allowed!')
        return team

class RoundAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RoundAdminForm
```

If `Round` is inline-edited in the change form page of `Team`, you could limit the [`max_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num) of `RoundInline`.

Answer (score 22):

I liked the way using the validator:

```
def restrict_amount(value):
    if Round.objects.filter(team_id=value).count() >= 3:
        raise ValidationError('Team already has maximal amount of rounds (3)')


class Team (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=30)


class Round (models.Model):
    round_number = models.IntegerField('Round', editable=False) #Auto-incrementing per Team
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, validators=(restrict_amount, ))
```

Using validator will make Django handle it properly, for example, display an error in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to to do this is by overriding the save() method which will through an error if your conditions are not met. One limit this from front end and overriding save() method will be for back end validations only.