# limit number of foreign key using Django CheckConstraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Django 4.1 and Postgresql and as stated in their documentation `CheckConstraint`  accept `Q` object and `Expression`.

Based on https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31646, I thought my solution would work, but when calling `makemigrations` nothing happens (`Count` inherit from `Func`).

**Goal:** I would like to limit the number of Messages per Discussion.

I did see a solution using a validators on the ForeignKey field but it is not robust (see  [Limit number of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586223/limit-number-of-foreign-keys)). I would prefer not to have to create a SQL function and calling it (would like a Django solution only).

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.lookups import IntegerLessThan

class Discussion(models.Model):
    MAX_MESSAGES = 10


class Message(models.Model):
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(
        "discussion.Discussion",
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name="messages",
    )
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            name="limit_discussion_messages",
            check=IntegerLessThan(
                models.Count("discussion", filter=models.Q(discussion=models.F("discussion"))),
                models.Value(Discussion.MAX_MESSAGES),
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

**EDIT:**
After some discussion in the comments and reading provided anwser here are my findings:
Perfect constraint (without data race) cannot be achieved with Django and no raw SQL in it's current state (4.1).

Using a Django solution only and it's validators system, you have two choices:

- Check before saving and accept the fact that you might have a few more records than the allowed limit
- Check after saving and accept the fact that you might rollback more operation than necessary, but allowed limit will be enforced

Comment: Any reason why you think validators would not be robust enough?

Comment: @nigel239, 2 checks can happen at the same time (because multiple request are handled in parallel) and so both request will have their validation OK and we will have one more record saved (having no database constraint, it is an allowed operation, we can call save() as many time as we want).
Sure, most likely it won't happen on a low traffic website, but still, we have a "data race" problem.

Comment: Why not use transaction logic for your queries in the validator? This will keep race conditions at bay. That being said; yes, if possible, database constraints will be better (For most cases).

Comment: Yeah I just thought of that, I could do the check after saving the item. We would still have datarace problem (2 save in parallel with 2 check in parallel, we would reverse them both while we could still reject only one of them and be at the limit that I want).
So without a DB constraint it is a matter of choice: do I really want the limit enforced ? Or having a few more items than the limit is not a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constraints` need to be in the `Meta` class([look here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints)):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(
        "discussion.Discussion",
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name="messages",
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
        name="limit_discussion_messages",
        check=IntegerLessThan(
            models.Count("discussion", filter=models.Q(discussion=models.F("discussion"))),
            models.Value(Discussion.MAX_MESSAGES),
        ),
        ),
    ]
```

## Other solutions:

### Solution 1:

Each model has a save() option that is called when the model is saved. You can check here and raise an error if the user already has 10 messages.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    discussion = models.ForeignKey("discussion.Discussion", models.CASCADE,related_name="messages")

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.id == None: #Creating a new object
            if Message.objects.filter(discussion=request.discussion).count() >= 10:
                #Raise whatever error you want or just return false
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Solution 2:

Using validators:

```
def restrict_amount(value):
        if Message.objects.filter(discussion=value).count() >= 3:
            raise ValidationError('You already have max amount of discussions (3)')
    
    class Message(models.Model):
        discussion = models.ForeignKey("discussion.Discussion",validators=(restrict_amount,))
```

Comment: omg, what a silly mistake (not putting it under Meta).
Well now the migration tell me that I cannot use aggregate function in CHECK constraint, I guess it is not possible then :/

Comment: Note: Using validators will only work on forms, unless you override the model `save()` method, and call `self.full_clean()` in there.

Comment: @Barbeuk So you can use other solutions! :)

Comment: @nigel239 both of them are correct! look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/

Comment: I did not say it was not correct. It just requires an extra step to always validate. (This will double validation on forms though.) See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run

Comment: @nigel239 I take your point! Thanks! :)